# TableSorter and link on rows of a column

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, tablesorter

I discovered TableSorter yesterday so it's obvious I don't understand much of it yet but I was able to add data from a csv url in a table via ajax.

Is it possible to add a link on a specific column?
for example i have a column "code" and i want that for each value of that column clicking on value goes to url ./page.php?code=VALUEOFCODE

so the value of code become for each row of the column "code" VALUEOFCODE

Comment: That sounds like something you should implement when you _create_ your table, it has very little to do with _sorting_ the data.

Comment: i know that is not related with the "sorting" but is it possible to interact with data retrived from url and modify them to visualize something different in table?